# How do I use a different library path for 32-bit builds in QBS?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qbs

In my QBS file I currently have:

```
cpp.libraryPaths: ["C:/Foo/x64/lib"]
```

which works OK with the 64-bit MinGW-w64 kit auto-detected by QT Creator.

But building with the 32-bit kit fails since the 32-bit libraries are in a different directory `C:/Foo/i686/lib`.

How do I configure it so that a different library path is used if the 32-bit MinGW-w64 kit is selected?

*Bonus question:* I'd like to get the base path `C:/Foo` from some local setting too, because on another development system I have the libraries in a different base path, not `C:/Foo`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the custom lib path on different machines, you can have a property that is set by passing a parameter to qbs if necessary:

```
 property path libPath: "C:/Foo"
```

And then `qbs build blahblah project.libPath:/path/to/lib`

In order to detect the build type, you can use the following format:

```
    Properties {
        condition: qbs.targetOS.contains("windows") && qbs.architecture === "x86"
        cpp.libraryPaths: [libPath + "/i686/lib"]
    }
    Properties {
        condition: qbs.targetOS.contains("windows") && qbs.architecture === "x86_64"
        cpp.libraryPaths: [libPath + "/x64/lib"]
    }
```

If you don't invoke qbs manually, you could set the parameter inside the project settings, however I feel like this kinda defeats the purpose if you have to change it on different machines.

In this regard, it would be better to set the `libPath` as an environment variable. Then simply read it via `Environment.getEnv("varName")`.

Comment: I'm invoking the build from QT Creator, not via qbs commandline ; can I set that libPath variable in QT Creator somehow?

Comment: You can enter properties in the details of the project build settings widget.